# Error updating DataTables-1.9.1 table by inserting rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table and I want to insert them rows that I get to a query, when I insert new rows, the table is not updated, and shows me that there are 0 entries, when I see that if the new rows added.
Also when I use the search field on the table the rows disappear.
The rows not the insert in the table to load the page, insert them if a function is executed.

```
    function build_table(valor){

         var objTabla = $("#tabla");
         var strNueva_Fila='<tr>'+
                '<td align="center"><img  class ="avatar1" src='+valor[0]+'></td>'+
                '<td>'+valor[1]+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+valor[2]+'</td>'+
                '<td >'+valor[3]+'</td>'+
                '<td >'+valor[4]+'</td>'+
                '<td >'+valor[5]+'</td>'+
                '<td >'+valor[5]+'</td>'+
                '<td >'+valor[5]+'</td>'+
            '</tr>';

    $(objTabla).find('tbody').append(strNueva_Fila);

    }


<table id ="tabla" >
    <thead>
        <th>Foto</th>
        <th>Nombre(s)</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Usuario</th>
        <th>Solap&iacute;n</th>     
        <th>Mostrar</th>
        <th>Editar</th>
        <th>Eliminar</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Inglés

This is a picture of the table to insert rows
[image]

And this happens when you use the option search

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dataTables 1.9.x You must use the builtin [**fnAddData**](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnAddData) function in order to insert new rows on a live dataTables instance.

Use either `<instance>.fnAddData()` or `$("#tabla").dataTable().fnAddData()`. Your code should look like this .

```
$("#tabla").dataTable().fnAddData([
   '<img class ="avatar1" src='+valor[0]+'>',
   valor[1],
   valor[2],
   valor[3],
   valor[4],
   valor[5]
]);
```

see demo of `fnAddData` in action here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/tnb0s4fc/**

The reason is that dataTables are building up an internal list of rows, which it is using upon showing the table, sorting, searching etc. When using jQuery or javascript to insert new `<tr>`'s, the new `<tr>` will be shown in the table, but dataTables are not aware of it - and then it will disappear as soon as the user click on a column header or the table for whatever reason is redrawn.